# target single element when it is not possible to use $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function modalClosed(){
    $("div#tab" + tabId).find('ul')
                        .prepend("<li>item</li>")
                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn('slow');
}
```

I want the list (`<li>`) to be prepended and have fade in effect one by one, unfortunately I have no way of using `$(this)`, the above code doesn't work well, it apply effect on all of the `<li>`.

Comment: How do you get the value of `tabId`. Is it a global variable?

Comment: @anupam does it matter? the problem is it doesn't fadeIn one by one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.prepend()` returns the `ul` element not the appended `li` element, so you are hiding/showing the `ul` element. You can reverse the logic using `prependTo()` method, now `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` are applied to the appended element not the `ul` element.

```
$("<li>item</li>").hide()
                  .prependTo("#tab"+tabId+" ul")
                  .fadeIn('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yj7v/

Comment: I set my li items to some html tag to var, when I do li.hide(), nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

```
function modalClosed(num) {
     $("div#tab" + tabId).find('ul')
                        .prepend("<li>item</li>")
                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn('slow', function() {
                            // callback function, called when fadeIn has finished
                            if(num > 1) {
                                modalClosed(num - 1);
                            }
                        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand You want fade in effect one by one on all li items. If that is correct then try the following:

```
var time=1000;
$("div#tab"+tabId+" ul").prepend("<li>item</li>");
$("div#tab"+tabId+" ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).fadeIn(time);
    time+= 800;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PV4dC/5/